# What's the complexity of comparison between two lists in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

If l1 and l2 are two lists, will `l1 = l2` cost `O(N)` or `O(1)`?

Futher questions:

If `l1=l2`, will l1 and l2 share the same physical memory?

How about strings? will `s1 = s2` cost `O(1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For structural comparison `=` you need to at least see all the data so it's (almost, see comment below) always O(n) both for lists and strings in the worst case (equal values). Physical comparison `==` is O(1) you just compare the pointers.

Note however that on your own data structures it is possible to implement structural comparison as physical comparison by ensuring, during value construction, that no two structurally equal values will use different physical memory. This is called hash-consing and you can find a more thorough explanation in [this](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/publis/hash-consing2.pdf) paper ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1159876.1159880)).

In general with lists you cannot infer from `l1 = l2` that they share the same physical memory since it depends on how they have been constructed as OCaml does not hash-cons lists. This also holds for strings.

Comment: I recall that the polymorphic compare function does a physical comparison before structural.

Comment: Yes it's an optimization, `a == b` implies `a = b` (see [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/libref/Pervasives.html#VAL(==))). So if `==` returns `true` you are done otherwise you cannot infer anything and you need to walk along the values (which is what will happen most of the time if your lists come from two different part of the program).

Comment: @DanielBünzli: except `nan` :P

Comment: Right... actually `a == b` implies `compare a b = 0` and [compare](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/libref/Pervasives.html#VALcompare) is compatible with `=` except in the treatment of `nan`s